How to fix "Error: creating CloudTrail Trail: InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket" in Terraform
Everytime I am trying to deploy my terraform code in Spacelift, I keep getting this error:

Error: creating CloudTrail Trail: InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket

Could you please help me with this?
# Create S3 bucket policy allowing CloudTrail to write logs
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_log_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:PutObject"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*"
        Condition = {
          StringEquals = {
            "s3:x-amz-acl" = "bucket-owner-full-control"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:GetBucketAcl"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.arn}"
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:ListBucket"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.arn}"
        Condition = {
          StringLike = {
            "s3:prefix" = ["AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_cloudtrail" "management_events" {
  name                       = var.cloudtrail_trail_name
  s3_bucket_name             = aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.id
  s3_key_prefix              = "cloudtrail-logs"
  is_multi_region_trail      = true
  enable_logging             = true
  enable_log_file_validation = true
  include_global_service_events = true

  cloud_watch_logs_role_arn  = aws_iam_role.cloudtrail_role.arn
  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudtrail_logs.arn}:*"
  kms_key_id                 = aws_kms_key.cloudtrail_key.arn

  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail,
    aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_log_bucket_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy.cloudtrail_role_policy,
    aws_kms_alias.cloudtrail_key_alias,
  ]

I did try changing the depends on for the S3 Bucket Policy as well as Cloudtrail a few times to no avail

Should this be a cross-account delivery of files to the bucket?

In this case, we are not using cross-account. It is in a single account.

From what I can see and comparing to the AWS docs, you are missing the same condition in two statements:
"aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:region:myAccountID:trail/trailName"

Adding that to the code you have should work:
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_log_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:PutObject"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.arn}/AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*"
        Condition = {
          StringEquals = {
            "s3:x-amz-acl"  = "bucket-owner-full-control"
            "aws:SourceArn" = "${aws_cloudtrail.management_events.arn}/${var.cloudtrail_trail_name}"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:GetBucketAcl"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.arn}"
        Condition = {
          StringEquals = {
            "aws:SourceArn" = "${aws_cloudtrail.management_events.arn}/${var.cloudtrail_trail_name}"
          }
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:ListBucket"
        Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_cloudtrail.arn}"
        Condition = {
          StringLike = {
            "s3:prefix" = ["AWSLogs/${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}/*"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

The last statement for listing the bucket shouldn't be needed for CloudTrail.

Hello Marko, Thank you for checking however I now get the error "Error: Cycle: aws_cloudtrail.management_events, aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_log_bucket_policy"

You can remove aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_log_bucket_policy from the depends_on, it's not needed.
